# Error in registering DLL

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, window

I'm trying to register DLL with command regsvr32 dll_name.dll but I'm getting below error

> The module "Addition.dll" was loaded but
>   entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found
>
> Make sure that "Addition.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try
>   again

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the problem?

Comment: @ilansch Yes I've written it

Comment: @djtechie - This question clearly belongs on `Stack Overflow` I have flagged the question so it can be migrated by a moderator.  As for solving the problem, if you want help, post all your method signatures within the file that creates `Addition.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every DLL you want to register must have the function DLLRegisterServer. This function is invoked whenever you run regsvr32.dll DLL_NAME. It modifies basically registry and just do things that need to install this dll into system.

From your error it is obvious that module "Addition.dll" doesn't have this function.
If it is custome made DLL , than add this function and run it again.

This Function is mainly used by COM (Component object model) components to register itself in system. DLL that will not used as COM server need not to have this function.

Comment: If you didn't have a DLLRegisterServer function and don't know why you need it, then maybe you don't need one and therefore shouldn't be registering it.