# How to registered DLL file in window server for Run in php code

Tags: php, laravel, dll

We want to run one dll file under php code(Laravel 5) using com class, regarding this we need registered dll file on my window server  (window 2012 R2) . But we are getting error.

The module "Addition.dll" was loaded but entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found
Make sure that "Addition.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again

We are using this line of command

REGSVR32 "C:\xampp\htdocs\Dll_demo\newton.dll" 
and 
regsvr32  newton.dll

Please let me know the exact way of Registered DLL  file in my window server (window 2012 R2).

I have checked lots of stack Overflow example 
[Error in registering DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646736/error-in-registering-dll)
But not getting any result from my side , Please help us. Thanks

Comment: This implies two tasks that you should adress separately: Firstly, how to register a COM component in MS Windows. Secondly, how to use a COM component from PHP. Also, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular "not getting any result from my side" is a mere interpretation of what you saw and expected and it's not helpful.

Comment: Ok thanks , let me check